# Change a Checksum Address to Its Normal Hex Value

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, addresses, web3.py, checksum

I know there are [functions](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#checkaddresschecksum) to convert hex address -> checksum address, but are there any to convert checksum address -> hex address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checksum addresses *are* hex addresses.

A checksummed address is simply an Ethereum address with some of the letters capitalized.

Hex Address: `0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8`

Checksummed Address: `0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8`

---

If you want a hex address from a checksummed address, simply convert the chekcsummed address to lower case with `address.toLowerCase()`.